# Why is my CodeIgniter website loading from bottom to top?

Tags: php, codeigniter

1. Default Controller is HomePage.php

   ```
   $route['default_controller'] = 'index/home_page';
   ```
2. Index.php

   ```
       public function home_page()
       {

         $data['subview']='subview/home_page';
         $this->load->view('_layout_home.php',$data);

       }
   ```
3. _layout_home.php

   ```
       <?php $this->load->view('include/header_home')?>
       <?php $this->load->view($subview)?>
       <?php $this->load->view('include/footer')?>
   ```
4. There is no autofocus attribute used in HTML or CSS.

The above code is for a home page of CodeIgniter web page which loads from bottom to top.

Comment: Try something like `$route['default_controller'] = 'controller/function';` and here is the guide https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: This is not working, The home_page is a function defined in the index.php. There is some another issue.Please check.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: _layout_header. php file is for that which load all the view

Comment: For the landing page

Answer (score 0):

> First letter only must be upper case on class and filename

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Change filename from

```
HomePage.php // Wrong Way
```

To

```
Homepage.php // Correct Way
```

Controller

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

> **Path application > controllers > Homepage.php**

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

```
<?php

class Homepage extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   public function index() {

   }

   public function home_page() {
       $data['subview']='subview/home_page';

       // No need for .php
       $this->load->view('layout_home',$data);
   }
}
```

Then on routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'homepage/home_page';
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

View

filename **layout_home.php**

```
<?php $this->load->view('include/header_home')?>
<?php $this->load->view($subview)?>
<?php $this->load->view('include/footer')?>
```

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'hompage/home_page'; hompage or homepage

Comment: in the home_page.php view page i have code for checking whether the user logged in or not                                    <?php 
                 $userType='';
                        if($this->Customer_m->isLoggedin() == TRUE)
                        {
       $userType=$this->session->userdata('customer_type'); 
      }
      ?> which is not working

Comment: That is a different question. Did my answer fix your main question if so please accept answer.

Comment: My issue is not fixed yet, I am explaining the scenario for one more time. I have 3 view for the landing page or home page.When i launch the website i got my page loading from bottom to top.